# sql get all month and year between 2 dates and calculate total as per the frequency of months between 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

employee:

```
emid stdt      enddt 

1    12jan2019 15dec2019 
2    12mar2019 12apr2019
3    12mar2018 12apr2018
4    12feb2019 Null
```

salary table:

```
empid salarypermonth
1     10000
2     20000
3     15000
4     10000
```

i want to list all months and its year between stdt and endt and total should be no of 
months * salary

desired o/p like:

```
month year  total expenditure
jan   2019  10000
feb   2019  10000
mar   2019  30000  -- total salary of 1 and 2 as employee 1 and 2 both got salary in mar
....
....
mar   2018  15000
....
```

so on.

Basically, i want to report out expenditure incurred by employer on salaries per month and year basis .
assuming employees gets salary as per salary table irrespective of date joined .

Comment: I removed the SQLite tag.  By preponderance of evidence, it seems to be SQL Server.

Comment: The fact that you have written your dates in the format such as `12jan2019` *infers* you're storing them as a `varchar` not a date; is that the case? (I hope not). Either, the query you are after isn't going to be SARGable with the columns as they are; as you have a `date`/`varchar` in one table, and a `varchar` and `year` in another. The some less than desirable design choices here.

Comment: We're not talking about Oracle here, @JoeDBAHAHAHA . And Oracle doesn't store dates in a format either. If you have seen them in an Oracla database, it's because someone chose the wrong data type.

Comment: @Larnu . . . I would not make that assumption.  People seem to write dates in their questions according to personal preferences.  Why questioners don't use YYYY-MM-DD format -- which is standard (ISO 8601), unambiguous, and locale-safe -- is beyond me.

Comment: 12jan2019 is for easy refrence , i have taken dates in format 01-12-2019 in sql server

Comment: @I agree, I wish people used `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyyMMdd`, however, for SQL Server the format `ddMMMyyyy` is *very* odd. That wouldn't be something that had "copy and pasted" from SSMS *unless* they really are using a `varchar`; and why I asked

Answer (score 0):

You can use a recursive CTE to expand the data and then aggregate:

```
with cte as (
      select datefromparts(year(e.stdt), month(e.stdt), 1) as yyyymm,
             e.enddt, e.emid, s.salary
      from employee e join
           salary s
           on e.emid = s.empid
      union all
      select dateadd(month, 1, yyyymm), enddt, emid, salary
      from cte
      where eomonth(yyyymm) < enddt
     )
select yyyymm, sum(salary)
from cte
group by yyyymm
order by yyyymm;
```

Answer (score 0):

A different approach, using a Tally, and `>=` and `<=` logic. This should perform better with larger datasets, and an rCTE (as it's name suggests) is recursive and therefore iterative:

```
USE Sandbox;
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Employee (emid int,
                           stdt date,
                           enddt date);
INSERT INTO dbo.Employee (emid,
                          stdt,
                          enddt)
VALUES (1, '20190112', '20191215'),
       (2, '20190312', '20190412'),
       (3, '20180312', '20190418'),
       (4, '20190212', NULL);
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.Salary (empid int,
                         salarypermonth int);
GO

INSERT INTO dbo.Salary (empid,
                        salarypermonth)
VALUES (1, 10000),
       (2, 20000),
       (3, 15000),
       (4, 10000);
GO

WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS(
    SELECT TOP (SELECT MAX(DATEDIFF(MONTH, stdt,GETDATE())) FROM dbo.Employee)
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) - 1 AS I
    FROM N N1, N N2), --100 months. Add more for more months
Dates AS(
    SELECT DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,E.stdt) AS MonthStart,
           EOMONTH(DATEADD(MONTH,T.I,E.stdt)) AS MonthEnd
    FROM Tally T
         CROSS APPLY (SELECT MIN(stdt) AS stdt FROM dbo.Employee) E)
SELECT DATENAME(MONTH, D.MonthStart)AS [Month],
       DATEPART(YEAR,D.MonthStart) AS [Year],
       SUM(S.salarypermonth) AS Salaries
FROM Dates D
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Employee E ON (D.MonthStart <= E.enddt OR E.enddt IS NULL)
                             AND D.MonthEnd >= E.stdt
     LEFT JOIN dbo.Salary S ON E.emid = S.empid
GROUP BY DATENAME(MONTH, D.MonthStart),
         DATEPART(YEAR,D.MonthStart)
ORDER BY CONVERT(date,CONCAT('01 ',DATENAME(MONTH, D.MonthStart),DATEPART(YEAR,D.MonthStart)),106) ASC;

GO
DROP TABLE dbo.Employee;
DROP TABLE dbo.Salary;
```